# Remove '\n' from each string stored in a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a python list in which look like this:

```
my_list = ['OFAC\n', 'Social Media Analytics\n', 'Teaching Skills\n', 'Territory...\n', 'Active Directory...\n', 'Business Research\n', 'Call Center...\n', 'Treatment of depression\n', 'VB\n', 'CAN\n', 'Client Interfacing...\n', 'Consolidated Financial...\n']
```

**How can i remove the \n from the end of each element and why is strip not working ?.**

I tried `line.strip('\n')` and `line.replace('\n','')` but it is not affecting anything.

The text file from which the list is made looks like this:

```
Java Basic
Core Java
C++
Python
...
```

Code for putting the textfile into the list is:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        st_line = line.strip('\n')
        d.append(st_line)
```

Comment: that should work. But what do you have in input? file or list?

Comment: try with `st_line = line.rstrip()`. However, do you have a list or an input file ?

Comment: Is it possible you're reading a file with DOS line endings (`\r\n`) in an environment expecting Unix (`\n`) line endings?

Comment: It seems like escape code problem.Maybe you can try (\\n)?

Comment: With that code you cannot end up with that list. You're not telling the truth.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I have an input file from which I'm transferring the contents into the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    d = map(str.rstrip, f.readlines())
print d
```

For your input above this will output:

```
['Java Basic', 'Core Java', 'C++', 'Python']
```